# Flutter Webview plugin doesn't open html page containing JavaScript with white spaces (U+00A0), No-Break Space

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutter-plugin, webview-flutter

I am trying to access the server URL (using the `webview_flutter 4.0.7` plugin) which includes javascript code with whitespaces, especially Unicode Character `(U+00A0)`, No-Break Space. It is Supposed to execute JS function clickNextButton() automatically when we load HTML page but the javascript function is not executing. However, if I remove whitespaces (Unicode Character `(U+00A0)`) from JavaScript code then WebView renders the HTML page with proper javascript code execution.

I cannot modify HTML code on server to remove white spaces and make it work because I don't have access to it, so I need a way to minify JS code in HTML using `Flutter WebView plugin`.

Comment: On which platform?  Where is the non-breaking space?  How is it encoded?  Can you create a small example that can reproduce the problem?  As a last resort, couldn't you preprocess the HTML and load it as a string?